# ¿Se puede ejecutar una consulta SQL con otra "collation"?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos en la que todas las tablas tienen la collation: utf8_general_ci
y quiero que una consulta SELECT se ejecute con la collation: utf8_spanish_ci

¿Es posible sin modificar las tablas? ¿Se puede con SQL estandar? ¿Como?

El proposito es hacer un buscador en varios idiomas. No es para producción.

Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el tipo de collation que pusiste entiendo que estás trabajando con MySql, no?  En ese caso deberías especificar el COLLATE cada vez que utilices un campo de texto al que quieras cambiarle el collation que tiene definido en la tabla, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT motivo COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci
FROM contactos
ORDER BY nombre COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias! Es lo que estaba buscando! Y si, estoy usando MySQL. Saludos!